# login to sharepoint 2010 site using tclsoap ,rest or http library

Tags: http, rest, soap, sharepoint-2010, tcl

I need an example of login by tcl  script from unix shell to sharepoint site. 
Which library I need to use for that?
Which method?
Currently have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Depends. Look at the headers.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I've used your example from your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237455/formating-tclsoap-request-for-login-to-sharepoint So as I understand I need to use NTLM authentication.