# Formating TclSOAP request for login to Sharepoint

Tags: authentication, soap, sharepoint-2010, tcl

I got this example from Sharepoint 2010 _vti_bin/Authentication.asmx?op=Login documentation.

```
POST /_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webil.marvell.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Login xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </Login>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How can I create the following Request to Sharepoint Server by TclSOAP?
Let say that Sharepoint server address is:

```
http://web.myintranet.com/
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? There are some examples there http://tclsoap.sourceforge.net/ Also here http://home.swipnet.se/lundin/tcl/tcl.html

Comment: @BrianFenton : Yes I did, but it is still not clear for me how to create authentication request. So I ask for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [TclWS](http://core.tcl.tk/tclws/doc/Release_2.3.7/docs/index.html).

With that it is easy to do that:

```
package require WS::Client
set sdef [WS::Client::GetAndParseWsdl http://web.myintranet.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx]
set service [dict get $sdef name] ; # Usually "Authentication", but who knows?
set response [::WS::Client::DoCall $service Login [list username Administrator password s3cr3t]]
```

I can't test that because our Sharepoint Server requires even some authentification to get the WSDL, so I usually fall back to my own scripts to do the authentification.

I suggest that you take a look at the headers that are returned, esp. the `WWW-Authenticate` headers. If `NTLM` is in that list, I could provide a script that can do that.

To get the headers simply execute:

```
puts [http::meta [http::geturl http://web.myintranet.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx]]
```

**Edit**:

To do NTLM Authentification [I wrote a wrapper arround `http::geturl`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6087#pagetoc5e7765ac) that could also be used for other things, but NTLM was at that time important.

So in your case you need that script and initialize it:

```
package require SASL::NTLM
source http-sasl.tcl; # That script is what I wrote on the wiki.
rename ::http::geturl ::http::geturl_orig; # Replace ::http::geturl with my wrapper.
set ::http::SASL::geturl ::http::geturl_orig; # Tell my wrapper the name of the original ::http::geturl
interp alias {} ::http::geturl {} ::http::SASL::geturl
proc ::http::SASL::WWW-SASLCB {reqt ctx cmd args} {
    switch -exact -- $cmd {
        login {return ""}
        username {return "Administrator"}
        password {return "s3cr3t"}
        realm {return "YOURDOMAIN"}
        hostname {return [info hostname]}
        default {return -code error unexpected}
    }
}
# Now the stuff from above:
package require WS::Client
set sdef [WS::Client::GetAndParseWsdl http://web.myintranet.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx]
set service [dict get $sdef name] ; # Usually "Authentication", but who knows?
set resposne [::WS::Client::DoCall $service Login [list username Administrator password s3cr3t]]
```

But the request fails with a `Server was unable to process request. ---> Site is not configured for Claims Forms Authentication.` error message.
But as far as I remember you don't need to call the webservice for login. Just access the protected resource. And if you can, pass `-keepalive 1` to every `http::geturl`.

Comment: I succeed to get headers response: "Server Microsoft-IIS/7.5 SPRequestGuid e22213b8-4fc5-49f6-975d-4b594465d74f WWW-Authenticate NTLM X-Powered-By ASP.NET MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices 14.0.0.6137 X-MS-InvokeApp {1; RequireReadOnly} Date {Wed, 27 Nov 2013 10:49:07 GMT} Connection close Content-Length 0"  
And I see it use NTLM for authentification. So may I ask for NTLM authentication example?

Comment: Added an example how **I** do NTLM authentification.